# Java Regular Expression's Pattern should be compiled as static data member or instance variable?

Tags: java, regex

I have a utility class which has all static methods and one of the method requires a regex matching.

Is it good practice to declare a pattern as static data member of the class or is it fine to declare it as instance variable of the method which is using that pattern?
This pattern is not getting used by multiple methods of the same class. 
Though this utility method can be called by multiple threads.

```
public final class Utility {
   public static someMethod(Sting in) {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("some pattern expression");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
      if (m.matches()) {
         //do something
      }
   }
}
```

Or below approach is better?

```
public final class Utility {
   private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("some pattern expression");
   public static someMethod(Sting in) {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
      if (m.matches()) {
         //do something
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The overhead of calling `compile` is not huge but I don't see any reason why you would not make it a static variable.

Comment: if multiple threads are calling someMethod(), then pre-compiled pattern (approach 2) is better as it is ready for usage rather than compiling for each call (approach 1)?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the Pattern class:

> Instances of this class are immutable and are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. Instances of the Matcher class are not safe for such use.

So the second version is possible. Decide for yourself if you consider it "better"; it's safe from a multithreading perspective.

Comment: In a test I ran using a simple regex, it ran 4 times faster reusing the pattern. Of course YMMV, but if it's used repeatedly in a tight loop, a static pattern can yield big benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine where and how often the pattern is going to be used in the Utility class.

If it's a regex that you need only for one particular method and it won't be used again anywhere else (in the foreseeable future) then declare it as an instance variable within that method.

If, on the other hand, it's a very reusable regex such as an email pattern, consider making it a static field. Then it can be accessed by all your utility methods.

Comment: `If it's a regex that you need only for one particular method and it won't be used again anywhere else` This is a wrong criteria. Even if there is only one method, if the method is repeatedly call thousands or millions of times, then it is a good idea to make it static.